# wordpress how to prevent load specific js in specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to prevent specific js in specific page for example suppose i have page name is `detail_event` and i would like to prevent load script `mouse.min` in this page .

I wrote following code in curent theme's functions.php but still `mouse.min` js is loading how to stop it.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_javascript', 100 );

function my_register_javascript() {
   if ( is_page('my-page') ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'mouse.min' ); 
     }
}
```

And location of mouse.min js is `mysite.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/mouse.min.js?ver=1.11.4`

please anyone know how to do this.

Comment: answered in full here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/262305/82677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things to be noticed here:

1. The handle for mouse.min.js is jquery-ui-mouse and not mouse.min
2. You are deregistering the script which means that as soon as that page is visited, WP will stop enqueuing this script in all pages.

Instead of doing that you should try below mentioned code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_wp_dequeue_script', 11 );
function custom_wp_dequeue_script() {
    if ( is_page('my-page') ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-ui-mouse' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's work but i want also remove "wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.min.js?ver=4.9.6" and i tried  name "mediaelement-wp-mediaelement.min" but not work

Comment: The handle is wrong again. The correct handle is **wp-mediaelement** Check the handle list here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: @samirsheikh Also if the answer resolves your issue please mark it as resolved.

Comment: What about 3rd party files from "random" plugins? Since they have no designated handle, they can't be blocked this way?

Comment: All enqueued script files have a designated handle. You can find hook for any enqueued script using a callback function to the hook `script_loader_tag`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the conditional include negative:

```
if ( !is_page('my-page') ) {
```